# Using RDL reports in Query Designer

Tags: rdl

Novice here, but I have a main RDL report and in the query designer I wish to reference another RDL report in the query designer is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by referencing another report, but you can put html link for another report in your RDL Report by using expressions or static link.

See [Add a Bookmark to a Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-bookmark-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) for link usage.

1. In Design view, right-click the text box, image, chart, to which you want to add a link and then click Properties.
2. In The Properties dialog box for that report item, click Action.
3. Select Go to bookmark. An additional section appears in the dialog box for this option.
4. In the Select bookmark box, type or select a bookmark or an expression that evaluates to a bookmark. Using the previous example, type BikePhoto to create a link to the image in your report.
5. Click OK.
6. (Optional) The text is not automatically formatted like a link. For text, it is helpful to change the color and effect of the text to indicate that the text is a link. For example, change the color to blue and the effect to underline in the Font section in the Home tab of the Ribbon.
7. To test the link, click Run to preview the report, and then click the report item that you set this link on..

---

If your intention is to embed another report in your active report, you can do it with Report Parts.
You need to create Report Parts and then you can insert your report part into your report.